# How change local time on Windows 8.1?

Tags: delphi, privileges

I have Delphi example:

```
function SetLocalTimeWin9xWinNT(const ADateTime: TDateTime): Boolean;
var
   ABuffer: LongWord;
   ATokenPriv, ATokenPrivOrg: TTokenPrivileges;
   AHandleToken: THandle;
begin
  if Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT then
  begin
    if not Windows.OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
      TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES or TOKEN_QUERY, AHandleToken) then
    begin
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;
    Windows.LookupPrivilegeValue(nil, 'SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME',
      ATokenPriv.Privileges[0].LUID);
    ATokenPriv.PrivilegeCount := 1;
    ATokenPriv.Privileges[0].Attributes := SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    if not Windows.AdjustTokenPrivileges(AHandleToken, FALSE, ATokenPriv,
      SizeOf(ATokenPriv), ATokenPrivOrg, ABuffer) then
    begin
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;
    Result := SetdateTime(ADateTime);
    Windows.AdjustTokenPrivileges(AHandleToken, FALSE, ATokenPrivOrg,
      SizeOf(ATokenPrivOrg), ATokenPriv, ABuffer);
    Windows.CloseHandle(AHandleToken);
    Result := True;
  end else
    Result := SetDateTime(ADateTime);
end;
```

where SetDateTime is Delphi function calling SetLocalTime. But If I try chenge to +5 minutes, I don't apply changes;
In Windows 8.1 need be differ privileges?

Comment: Please show the exact function call that you're executing to attempt to change the time.  Please also show how you're checking the time before and after the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Changing time requires admin privileges. You'll need to do this inside a process that is elevated.

Comment: My program must be run with admin privileges (how test if it running with admin privileges?) or need changes in procedure above?

Comment: Add the requireAdministrator option in your manifest. Elevation has to happen as process is created.